# Conditional regex does not match the else part

Tags: python, regex

I am using python flavoured regex to conditionally match a string. The sample string is given below:

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 http://domain/STRING1/part1/part2/part3/part4/part5/ABC000495835__CD__XYZ__ABCD__ABC__ABCDEF__ENG.xyz field8 field9 field10

field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 http://domain/STRING2/part1/part2/part3/part4/part5/ABC000495835.xyz field8 field9 field10
```

The conditions for extraction are as below:

1. When STRING1 is present in the 7th field, the characters between the last / and first _ should be extracted.
2. When STRING2 is present in the 7th field, the characters starting from the last / till space should be extracted.

I have written the following regex:

```
(?i)^(?:[^ ]*( {1,2})){6}(?:[a-z]+://[-A-Z0-9.\:]+/)(STRING1/)?(?:[^ /]+/)*(?P<myField>(1)?[^_]+|[^ ]+)
```

While this regex works correctly for the first sample string, for the second string, it extracts "ABC000495835.xyz field8 field9 field10".

Please tell me where I am going wrong and why the if part of the conditional regex is always matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group 1 in your regex is `( {1,2})`, group 2 is `(STRING1/)`, so you need to adjust your conditional accordingly.

Also, you got the conditional syntax wrong. It should be

```
(?i)^(?:[^ ]*( {1,2})){6}(?:[a-z]+://[-A-Z0-9.\:]+/)(STRING1/)?(?:[^ /]+/)*(?P<myField>(?(2)[^_]+|[^ ]+))
```

Result:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?i)^(?:[^ ]*( {1,2})){6}(?:[a-z]+://[-A-Z0-9.\:]+/)(STRING1/)?(?:[^ /]+/)*(?P<myField>(?(2)[^_]+|[^ ]+))")
>>> regex.search("field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 http://domain/STRING1/part1/part2/part3/part4/part5/ABC000495835__CD__XYZ__ABCD__ABC__ABCDEF__ENG.xyz field8 field9 field10").group("myField")
'ABC000495835'
>>> regex.search("field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 http://domain/STRING2/part1/part2/part3/part4/part5/ABC000495835.xyz field8 field9 field10").group("myField")
'ABC000495835.xyz'
```